# OnClick method kills android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I have a simple messaging application that gets the text of an editText box and sends it to the server. All I want to do is when the text gets sent to the server, I want the editText box to reset.

Here is my code that works but, it doesn't reset the editText box:

```
public void sendMessage(View v) {
        Editable messagetext;

        messagetext = message.getText();

        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        username = prefs.getString("username", "null");

        where = prefs.getString("chat", "null");
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inptbox);

        function = new Functions();

        response = function
                .sendMessage(username, where, messagetext.toString());

    }
```

If I add one more line of code, in order to reset the box my application dies:

```
public void sendMessage(View v) {
    Editable messagetext;

    messagetext = message.getText();
        message.setText("");
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    username = prefs.getString("username", "null");

    where = prefs.getString("chat", "null");
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inptbox);

    function = new Functions();

    response = function
            .sendMessage(username, where, messagetext.toString());

}
```

The error I get (bear with me, I'm not that good logcat) is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(7207): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

List of global variables:

```
String username = "";
    Functions function;
    EditText message;
    String response = "";
    String where = "";
    String inboxx;
```

Comment: Could you post the whole logcat error log with the red text.

Comment: Updated in my question. "List of Global variables"

Comment: I agree with Tim, it looks like you are trying to access message before it is defined.  Try putting `message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inptbox);` in your `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
messagetext = message.getText();                 
...
message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inptbox);  
...
```

Should not the order of these be reversed? You should need to say what 'message' is before you call `getText` on it.

Comment: ...unless 'message' is defined as an instance variable, which would be sort of weird.

Comment: Oh my. How did I overlook that? That's exactly what it was. I wonder why it was working correctly when the reset code wasn't implemented though.